# Is it a way to transform XML using XSLT Regex

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Test Data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Declaration>
  <AcceptanceDateTime>2011-05-01</AcceptanceDateTime>
  <ID>CA  0011112347</ID>
  <GovernmentAgencyGoodsItems>
  <GovernmentAgencyGoodsItem>
    <SequenceNumeric>1</SequenceNumeric>
    <Description>PHENOLIC RESIN COATING (THIXON IS BRAND) THIXON P-14 5 GAL/PAIL</Description>
  </GovernmentAgencyGoodsItem>
  <GovernmentAgencyGoodsItem>
    <SequenceNumeric>2</SequenceNumeric>
    <Description>THIXON 520</Description>
  </GovernmentAgencyGoodsItem>
</GovernmentAgencyGoodsItems>
</Declaration>
```

I expect the transformed result as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Declaration>
  <DECL_DATE>2011-05-01</DECL_DATE>
  <DECL_ID>CA  0011112347</DECL_ID>
  <GoodsItems>
    <GoodsItem>
      <SEQ>1</SEQ>
      <Descp1>PHENOLIC RESIN COATING (THIXON IS </Descp1>
      <Descp2>BRAND) THIXON P-14 5 GAL/PAIL</Descp2>
      <Descp3></Descp3>
    </GoodsItem>
    <GoodsItem>
      <SEQ>2</SEQ>
      <Descp1>THIXON 520</Descp1>
      <Descp2></Descp2>
      <Descp3></Descp3>
   </GoodsItem>
 </GoodsItems>
</Declaration>
```

Is it possible to transform XML using "xsl:analyze-string" to split every 35 characters into groups, and set the values for elements from DESCP1 to DESCP3.

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="Description" regex="\b[\s\S]{0,35}\b">
  <xsl:matching-substring>
<Descp1>
  <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)" />
</Descp1>
<Descp2>
  <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)" />
</Descp2>
<Descp3>
  <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(3)" />
</Descp3>
  </xsl:matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

Please help me.

Comment: The regular expression syntax used with XSLT and XPath 2.0 and later does not support `\b` for word boundaries I think so that is not going to work. You can of course use `.{0,35}` to match on 35 characters. It is not clear whether you always want to create `Descp1/2/3` elements or what is supposed to happen if the original description matches more than three items.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will give you roughly the right effect:

```
    <xsl:variable name="pat">.{1,35}(\s|$)</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:analyze-string select="$in" regex="{$pat}">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:element name="desc{position()}">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
```

You might want to fine-tune it for example to control which characters are treated as whitespace, to retain/discard whitespace delimiters, or to deal with the case where more than three lines are generated.

Your code isn't going to work for (at least) 2 reasons:

1. The \b isn't recognized in the XPath regex dialect
2. regex-group() isn't useful when your regex has no capturing groups

Comment: Your pattern contains a capturing group *(\s|$)* but you don't use it. Why did you put it?

Comment: Because XPath 2.0 doesn't support non-capturing groups.

Comment: I tried but failed. The "xsl:analyze-string" cannot be put inside an element.Would you give me a complete XSLT file. Thanks

Comment: No, if your code doesn't work then you need to fix it, not to give up and ask someone else to write it. If you can't fix it yourself, then tell us what you did and tell us how it failed.